# Using an array as function parameter php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I would like to pass to a function as a parameter.  These array values will be used to pull values out of another array and display them.

My Function:

```
function showTreadmills($listbrands) {
    global $treadmills;
    foreach( $treadmills as $brand=>&$features ) {
        if ($brand == $listbrands) { 
            return '<p>'.$features["description"].'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Treadmills Array:

```
$treadmills = [
    'bowflexseries3' => [
        'description' => 'Bowflex Series 3',
        'image' => '/images/bowflex-series-3-150x150.jpg',
        'url' => '/treadmills/bowflex/series-3',

    ],
    'solef85' => [
        'description' => 'Sole F85',
        'image' => '/images/sole-f85-150x150.jpg',
        'url' => '/treadmills/sole/f-85',
    ],
    'endurancet10hrc' => [
        'description' => 'Endurance T10HRC',
        'image' => '/images/endurance-t10hrc-150x150.jpg',
        'url' => '/treadmills/endurance/t10hrc',
    ]
];
```

Values that I'm trying to pull out of array in my function:

```
 <?php echo showTreadmills('bowflexseries3','solef85'); ?>
```

This only returns the first Description from the array, which is Bowflex Series 3. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to pull the description for bowflexseries3 and solef85.  I'm sure it's a dumb oversight.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a reference in `=>&$features`? You only need to use a reference if you're going to modify the variable and want it to affect the original array. If you're just reading the variable, there's no point in making it a reference variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing an array to the function, you're passing two strings. You need to call `array()` to wrap an array around them:

```
echo showTreadmills(array('bowflexseries3','solef85'));
```

Then you need to change `showTreadmills`. You can't use `==` to compare a string to an array. It looks like you want to test whether the string is in the array, so it should be:

```
if (in_array($brand, $listbrands))
```

Or instead of looping through `$treadmills` and testing whether it's equal to one of `$listbands`, you could loop through `$listbrands`:

```
$result = '';
foreach ($listbrands as $brand) {
    if (isset($treadmills[$brand])) {
        $result .= '<p>'.$treadmills[$brand]["description"].'</p>';
    }
}
return $result;
```

This is better, since it loops through the smaller array. And `in_array()` has to do a search, while accessing an associative array is just a hash lookup.

Notice that you need to concatenate the results into a string during the loop. If you use `return` in the loop, you'll only return the first brand found.

Comment: Would looping through $listbrands have an advantage, performance wise or other, since my $treadmills array will eventually be much larger?

Comment: Yes, it's better. I've updated the answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning on your first match:

```
if ($brand == $listbrands) { 
        return '<p>'.$features["description"].'</p>';
}
```

You will need to store all your matches so the entire loop can finish and then send back everything that matched.

```
$matches = '';
foreach( $treadmills as $brand=>&$features ) {
    if ($brand == $listbrands) { 
        $matches .= '<p>'.$features["description"].'</p>';
    }
}
return $matches;
```

Comment: Not sure why I got the downvote,  my answer is spot on!

Comment: yeah you are right!.. make sure you edit properly.. so that you make it more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function showTreadmills($listbrands) {
    global $treadmills;

    $out = '';
    foreach( $treadmills as $brand=>&$features ) {
        if ($brand == $listbrands) { 
            $out .= '<p>'.$features["description"].'</p>';
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```